# Class B and C Airpsace Ring Data in Text

Tags: airspace, datasets

Class B and Class C airspace has multiple rings where each ring can be a custom polygon shape.

[image]

I want to extract following data into text:

1. the shape of these polygon rings in lat/long (ideally a geoJson object)
2. distance between the rings and
3. high / low limit for each ring

Is this data available for free or purchase?

Comment: [FAA NFDC](https://nfdc.faa.gov/xwiki/bin/view/NFDC/56DaySub-2015-06-25) should be the place (for the US).

Comment: You might also try asking at [GIS.SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @mins thanks. this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @mins you should turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

For the US, the FAA [National Flight Data Center (NFDC)](https://nfdc.faa.gov/xwiki/bin/view/NFDC/56DaySub-2015-06-25) is the place. There is this set of files: *Class B,C,D,E Airspace Shape Files*, which is free and contains borders of airspaces in the GIS [shapefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) format.